# how can I find this limit .

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

-for    $$\alpha \in \left] 0;1\right[$$

-evaluate  $$\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\prod _{k=0}^{n}\left( 
 1+\alpha^{2^{k}}\right)$$

Comment: Multiply by $1-\alpha$

Comment: wow man this stack is so sensitive ,always about to implode ...calm down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$P=\prod _{k=0}^{n}\left( 
 1+\alpha^{2^{k}}\right) = (1+\alpha)(1+\alpha^{2})(1+\alpha^{2^{2}})\cdots \cdots (1+\alpha^{2^{n}})$$

Multiply both numerator and Denominator by $(1-\alpha)$

We get $$P = \frac{(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha)(1+\alpha^{2})(1+\alpha^{2^{2}})\cdots \cdots (1+\alpha^{2^{n}})}{(1-\alpha)} = \frac{1-\alpha^{2^{n+1}}}{1-\alpha}$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-\alpha^{2^{n+1}}}{1-\alpha} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$$

because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\alpha^{2^{n+1}} = 0$ when $\alpha \in (0,1)$